# Why can't a generic lambda call itself, but wrapping it in a class allows it?

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, lambda, c++14

Here is the full example:

```
auto callSelf = [](auto& func) {func(func);};

class wrapper : public decltype(callSelf) {
    using base = decltype(callSelf);
public:
    wrapper() : base(callSelf) {}

    template<class T>
    void operator()(T& func) {
        base::operator()(func);
    }
};

int main()
{
    //callSelf(callSelf); // Error
    wrapper w;
    w(w); // OK, nice endless recursion
}
```

Why is it possible with the wrapper, while doing it directly causes the following error?

```
main.cpp:30: error: use of '<lambda(auto:1&)> [with auto:1 = <lambda(auto:1&)>]' before deduction of 'auto'
 auto callSelf = [&](auto& func) {func(func);};
                                  ~~~~^~~~~~
```

Comment: Your okay case should still have an error because `callSelf` has a capture when it isn't local to anything. You reduced your code to an example that introduces a new error.

Comment: @chris oh, sorry, caputre is not necessary here, editing. But with the capture it should make compile-time error or ill-form the program?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly why. What's unclear about it?

Comment: @n.m.: That error message is not clear at all.

Comment: To be fair, clang's error message is more precise: *function ... **with deduced return type** cannot be used before it is defined*. Add an explicit return type and the error goes away.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Sorry I didn't think about this message too deeply. You get the same message without any generic lambdas simply by `auto callself2 = []() { callself2(); }` The `auto` in "before deduction of ‘auto’" refers to the return type. It is indeed not very clear.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is actually quite tricky. The rule you're running afoul of is in [dcl.spec.auto]:

> If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed to determine the type of an expression, the program is ill-formed.

That is what's going wrong here:

```
auto callSelf = [](auto& func) {func(func);};
callSelf(callSelf);
```

We need to know the type of `callSelf` to determine the type of the expression of `func(func)`, which it iself circular. This is easily resolvable by simply specifying the return type:

```
auto callSelf = [](auto& func) -> void {func(func);};
callSelf(callSelf); // ok. I mean, infinite recursion, but otherwise ok. ish.
```

However, when you *wrap* the lambda, you get different behavior. This line here:

```
w(w);
```

is passing an object of type `wrapper` into, effectively, the lambda. That is not its own type. The body of the lambda invokes that object on itself, but we know the type of that expression. You declared it:

```
template<class T>
void operator()(T& func) {
~~~~~
```

This function works (for some definition of works) with `void` for the same reason the lambda worked when we added `-> void`. It's no longer an undeduced placeholder. We already know the return type. To get the same behavior as with the lambda, change the declaration of `operator()` to be `auto`.

Answer (score 8):

In your case, simply define the return type and the compiler should accept it:

```
auto callSelf = [](auto& func) -> void {func(func);};

class wrapper : public decltype(callSelf) {
    using base = decltype(callSelf);
public:
    wrapper() : base(callSelf) {}

    template<class T>
    void operator()(T& func) {
        base::operator()(func);
    }
};

int main()
{
    callSelf(callSelf); //works
    wrapper w;
    w(w); //ok, nice endless recursion
}
```

With return type deduction, the compiler cannot use the lambda in the lambda itself because the compiler has to see the body of the function to deduce the return type. The fact that the compiler has to check the body of the function make it see the content of your lambda that uses the lambda itself. Since the compiler is in the deduction process, you cannot use the lambda, hence the compilation error.

Comment: Why isn't it such that if there is no `return` statement, a function with deduced return type gets return type `void`? Otherwise, how could you convince the compiler that the lambda has return type `void` by having it deduce it? It appears that if the body is `if(0) return void(); func(func);`, it works. But is there a better solution?

Comment: Yes, but in order to check if there is no return statement, the compiler still have to check the body of the function, and the whole body of the function must be well defined. Since in the body you use a function that it's return type is yet to be determined, the function body is ill-formed and the compilation fails.